# How to pass in an optional parameter in request body conditionally?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an optional parameter called activationCodes which is defined as:

```
(property) PS.Components.Schemas.IC.activationCodes?: string[] | null | undefined
```

In my request body in my function, I only want to send in `activationCodes` as a field if another variable string is defined:

I tried it as:

```
  const reqBody: PS.Components.Schemas.IC = {
    description: input.description,
    outcome: input.outcome,
    activationCodes: aCode ? [aCode] : undefined,
  };
```

but this results in `activationCodes: undefined` in the `reqBody` if `aCode` is undefined. Is it possible to completely ignore the `activationCodes` field if `aCode` is undefined?

Comment: If you need to do it in one line you can use conditional object spread [like this](https://tsplay.dev/NBjK4N).  But right now your question code isn't a [mre]; could you make it such?  That is, could you remove references to undeclared types/values so that someone can just paste the code into a standalone IDE to demonstrate the issue for themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it after:

```
const reqBody: PS.Components.Schemas.IC = {
  description: input.description,
  outcome: input.outcome,
};

if (aCode) reqBody.activationCodes = [aCode];
```